# Duplicate mappings for scala-library-2.10.3.jar with sbt-native-packager 0.7+

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, runtimeexception, sbt-native-packager

I'm stuck with Play 2.2.6 and Scala 2.10 for a project. `sbt-native-packager` 0.6.4 is compatible, but has a bug I can't live with (passing a relative path to `scriptClasspath` throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing`). I see this got fixed in `sbt-native-packager` 0.7.0.

Unfortunately, when I try the `sbt stage` task using `sbt-native-packager` 0.7.0 or later I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate mappings:
/work/myProject/target/universal/stage/lib/org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar
from
/opt/play-2.2.6/repository/local/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.3/jars/scala-library.jar
/home/mslinn/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.3.jar
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a shortcut and patched the 0.6 branch so I could fix the error there. Here is the [forked GitHub project](https://github.com/mslinn/sbt-native-packager/tree/0.6), complete with instructions on how to install it.